# Add comma to the end of every line in a text file PHP

Tags: php, file

I started learning PHP this week and need to add a comma to the end of every line in a text file. I don't really know where to start. What would I do after I load the file? I can't find any tutorial saying how to write to the end of every line only the beginning of the file or end?? Is it possible to specify the end of a every line?

What I have so far:

```
 fopen("file.txt",a)
 ????
```

I'm using "a" because I want to preserve the data.

Comment: a=append, w=write and r=read. Not all tags in php script must be added by comma :D there are hundreds google's lib outside there about it.

Comment: The term is called "concatenation". Use it in a `foreach` or at the end of each line being written.

Comment: yeah, it's nice weekend to start to learn as I did long ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just get all file lines with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then I go through each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and concatenate a comma at the end. After this I save the file with the new content with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){return $v . "," . PHP_EOL;}, $lines);
    file_put_contents("test.txt", $lines);

?>
```

Example file:

```
a
a
a
```

after the script:

```
a,
a,
a,
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to add a comma to an empty line just add a condition to check if the line is empty or not like this:

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){return $v . (empty($v)?"":",") . PHP_EOL;}, $lines);
    file_put_contents("test.txt", $lines);

?>
```

Comment: he isn't asking anything but can the op use a every line?

Comment: @don I don't really understand what you mean with this comment ^ ?

Comment: in that question, the OP asked: "Is it possible to specify the end of a every line?" that's the real question, not : What would I do after I load the file?, but now you explain it little bit. that's better

Comment: Great thanks. array_map looks to be the thing I needed

Comment: @don OP asked this too: *What would I do after I load the file?* :D But I see what you mean now!

Comment: Is there anyway I can only add to lines that are not blank. Currently I am adding the comma to every single line even if blank?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace all the EOL with some specific character ?

```
$EOLChar=",";
$myFile = fopen("file.txt", "r") ;
$newFile="";
while(!feof($myFile)) {
    $newFile.= str_replace(PHP_EOL, $EOLChar, fgets($myFile));
}
fclose($myFile);
file_put_contents("file.txt", $newFile);
```

Comment: With this you are opening the file twice, because `file_put_contents()` is like: `fopen(), fwrite(), fclose()`. So you could open the file in `r+` go through each line and directly write in the file with `fwrite()`

Comment: @Rizier123 Yaa will be more efficient way of doing this.